# Normalization of $U(1)$ gauge fields

Tags: gauge-theory, conventions, yang-mills, normalization, chern-simons-theory

In G. W. Moore, “Introduction to Chern-Simons theories.” 2019 TASI School. [Online]. Available: [https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/TASI-ChernSimons-StudentNotes.pdf](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/TASI-ChernSimons-StudentNotes.pdf) the $U(1)$ gauge field has a normalization such that $F/2\pi$ has integral periods.

Assume you have a $U(1)$ gauge field and let $\Sigma$ be some closed 2-surface, say a sphere. Then we can slice $\Sigma$ into a northern hemisphere $N$ and a southern hemisphere $S$. Each is contractible and thus, on each the $U(1)$ bundle must be trivial. Accordingly, there must be sections of said bundle on each of these hemispheres allowing us to define the Yang-Mills fields $A_N$ on $N$ and $A_S$ on $S$. On each of these patches $F=dA_N$ and $F=dA_S$, and the Yang-Mills fields are related on any overlap between $N$ and $S$, say the equator $E$, by a gauge transformation $A_N=A_S+ig^ {-1}dg$, for some function $g:E\rightarrow U(1)$. Then we have
$$\int_\Sigma F=\int_N F+\int_S F=\int_N dA_N+\int_S dA_S=\int_E A_N-\int_E A_S=\int_E(A_N-A_S)=i\int_E g^{-1}dg.$$
All possible maps $g$ are of the form $g(\theta)=e^{i\varphi(\theta)}$ for some $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with a definite winding number $n$, i.e. $\varphi(2\pi)=\varphi(0)+2\pi n$. Then
$$\int_\sigma F=-\int_Ed\varphi=-2\pi n.$$
Thus $F/2\pi$ has integer periods. Where did I assume any convention on the normalization of the gauge field?

By the way, I know the above is only a proof for $E$ homeomorphic to a sphere. I don't know how to proof this in general. Any comments on this would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You assumed the normalization when you wrote
$$
 A_N=A_S+ig^{-1}dg.
\tag{1}
$$
To make this more intuitive, consider a triangulation of the closed *orientable* 2-surface $\Sigma$. (I won't consider unorientable surfaces.) Let $T$ be the set of triangles, oriented so that whenever two triangles share an edge, the edge is oriented oppositely in the two triangles. Assign a group element $u(t)$ to each triangle $t\in T$ such that
$$
 \prod_{t\in T} u(t) = 1.
\tag{2}
$$
The quantities $u(t)$ are called **plaquette variables**. Given such an assignment, we can also choose a group element $u(\ell)$ for each edge $\ell$ such that
$$
 u(t)=\prod_{\ell\in t}u(\ell), 
\tag{3}
$$
where the edges are understood to be oriented monotonically around the triangle $t$, and where
$$
 u(-\ell)u(\ell) = 1
\tag{4}
$$
where $-\ell$ is the reversed-orientation version of $\ell$. The quantities $u(\ell)$ are **link variables**. The assignment $\ell\mapsto u(\ell)$ is not uniquely determined by the assignment $t\mapsto u(t)$, because we can replace
$$
 u(\ell)\to u^g(\ell)
\tag{5a}
$$
with
$$
 u^g(\ell)\equiv g^{-1}(v_1)u(\ell)g(v_2),
\tag{5b}
$$
where $v_1,v_2$ are the initial/final points of the orienged edge $\ell$, where $g(v)\in U(1)$ for each vertex $v$ in the triangulation. The plaquette variables (3) are invariant under the **gauge transformation** (5).

To relate this to the usual concept of a gauge field, write
$$
 u(\ell)=\exp\left(ic\int_\ell A\right)
\tag{6}
$$
for a one-form $A$, with a normalization constant $c$ that is the same for all links, and consider the limit as the size of the triangles in $T$ goes to zero. Such a one-form $A$ may not exist globally, and that's okay. The plaquette variables $u(t)$ can be written
$$
 u(t)\equiv \exp\left(ic\int_t F\right)
\tag{7}
$$
with $F=dA$. Using different one-forms $A$ in different patches corresponds to using a different choice of link variables $u(\ell)$ in different patches, related to each other by (5) where the patches overlap. Originally I used (5) to describe a gauge transformation, and here I'm using it to describe a **transition function**. To relate this to (1), write $v_2=v_1+\ell$ and consider
$$
 \omega \equiv \lim_{|\ell|\to 0}\frac{u^g(\ell)-1}{|\ell|}.
\tag{8}
$$
From the left-hand side of (5b), we get
$$
 \omega = ic A^g(v_1).
\tag{9}
$$
From the right-hand side of (5b), we get
$$
 \omega = icA(v_1) + g^{-1}(v_1)dg(v_1).
\tag{10}
$$
Altogether, $ic A^g(v_1) = icA(v_1) + g^{-1}(v_1)dg(v_1)$. Aside from the different sign-convention for $i$, this shows that (1) assumes the normalization $c=1$. We can't cancel the factor of $c$ by replacing $g\to g^c$, because replacing $g\to g^c$ is the same as applying a $c$-dependent gauge transformation. A gauge transformation is unable to change the product $\prod_{\ell\in L}u(\ell)$, or the integral $\oint_L A$ modulo $2\pi$, around any closed loop $L$.

The freedom to change the normalization factor $c$ comes from the fact that what really matters is the link variables $u(\ell)$, not the one-form $A$, because we're using a gauge theory based on the *compact* group $U(1)$, not on the non-compact group $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $A$ and $F$ are always confined to the exponents in (6) and (7), so we can normalize $A$ arbitrarily and use the constant $c$ to compensate.

From this perspective, the proof of integer periods for a general closed *orientable* 2-surface $\Sigma$ is easy: (2) holds by construction if we write the plaquette variables in terms of link variables as in (3) and (4), which is the essence of the concept of a gauge field.

Comment: This is a really interesting point of view! Thanks for sharing! Why is it that the plaquette variables have to multiply to 1? Also, could you help me understand from the continuous point of view why it is that $A_N=A_S+ig^{-1}dg$ assumes a normalization? If I multiply both $A_N$ and $A_S$ by a constant $c$ then the relation remains correct as long as I replace $g$ by $g^c$.

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano The plaquette variables must multiply to $1$ because the gauge field consists of the map $\ell\to u(\ell)\in U(1)$, and the product on the left-hand side of (2) contains each edge $\ell$ exactly twice, with opposite orientations, so (4) implies (2). Regarding the normalization from the continuous point of view, I added more detail to the answer, around the new equations (8)-(10).